# mysql order by performance optimization

Tags: mysql, performance, sql-order-by

Hi I like to make a perfomant order by query.
This is my query:

```
SELECT a.status,a.title,a.id,
b.deployed,b.accepted,b.rejected,b.error
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON ( a.id = b.id )
WHERE b.agencyid = 1 AND a.userid = 3
ORDER BY a.date DESC
LIMIT 0,50
```

without the ORDER BY clause the query takes 0.006 s
with the ORDER BY clause it needs 1.1181 s !!!

The most time consumption comes from Copying To Tmp Table   1,1 s   99,78%  1   1,1 s
How I can decrease the Copy to tpm table time?

Comment: Use indexing on date column of a table .

Comment: where is your temp table? I dont see it in above code. Are you sure its just this part that takes long time or you have a proc ando ther queries as well?

Comment: Please provide: 1. Complete schemas for both tables (using `SHOW CREATE TABLE`) 2. `EXPLAIN` for the given query. PS: is it intentionally that one of predicates over table `b` is in `WHERE` clause not in `ON`? If so - why it's `LEFT JOIN` not `INNER JOIN` then?

Comment: This is an inner join. Remove the LEFT Keyword

Answer (score 0):

First, as noted by Strawberry, because you have the "b" alias referenced in the where clause, and not considering NULL, it in essence turns your left join to an INNER JOIN.

```
SELECT 
      a.status,
      a.title,
      a.id,
      b.deployed,
      b.accepted,
      b.rejected,
      b.error
   FROM a JOIN b 
      ON a.id = b.id
   WHERE 
          a.userid = 3
      AND b.agencyid = 1 
   ORDER BY 
      a.date DESC
   LIMIT 
      0,50
```

If you meant for it to be a LEFT-JOIN (all "a" records regardless of a match in the "b" table), then you would need to move your "b" qualifier to the JOIN clause.

```
SELECT 
      a.status,
      a.title,
      a.id,
      b.deployed,
      b.accepted,
      b.rejected,
      b.error
   FROM a LEFT JOIN b 
      ON a.id = b.id
      AND b.agencyid = 1 
   WHERE 
      a.userid = 3
   ORDER BY 
      a.date DESC
   LIMIT 
      0,50
```

That being said, you are looking for a specific user ordered by date.  I would have your "a" table indexed on (userid, date) so the engine can be optimized on your WHERE qualifier AND the order by and should resolve your performance issue regardless of left and inner join...

To help the join condition to your "b" table, index it on (id, agencyid)

Comment: @masterofweb, did this help or even answer your issue encountered?  It still appears open.  Also, please look into this site's HELP -> TOUR for basic etiquette.